# How to set timezone in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, timezone

I have a such query to database:

```
SELECT * FROM screenings WHERE time(time)>time('now') ORDER BY time(time);
```

It works fine when the time zone is set to GMT+0:00. But if timezone has a different meaning (for example, GMT+6:00), database query results are in accordance with the GMT+0:00 and, respectively, the displayed information does not match the current time.

So, my question is how to set the local timezone in SQLite?

Thanks.

Comment: As has been said, save your times in UTC format. There's actually a very good reason to do so - if a person travelling moves into a different timezone their device will adjust to it. In such a case, any date/time saved using local timezone in the DB will no longer be valid and you'll have a real headache adjusting accordingly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't store values with timezone in the first place. Instead, normalize your data to UTC and use UTC consistently in your queries.

Only when formatting the data for display purposes, adjust for user's local timezone.

Comment: I agree with storing the dates/time in UTC, but when executing a query on the database, it is necessary to consider the local timezone, otherwise records outside the desired period will be returned. Finally, yes, when delivering the data to the users continue to consider the local time zone.

Answer (score 4):

Save data in `UTC Timezone.` when you need to display then fetch data then convert into user's `Timezone`

Answer (score 2):

It would be a better idea to record all time information as UTC.  When you wish to display the time to the user you should format it then to their own time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Besides saving all dates using the UTC timezone, I would also consider storing which timezone those timestamps refer to, if it makes sense for your application.

The rationale behind storing both a UTC timestamp as returned by `Calendar.getTimeInMillis()` and the timezone is that if you store a timestamp (e.g., 3:15 pm at your local timezone/1:15 pm UTC), then fly to a different timezone, and then retrieve the timestamp, a different offset will be applied to the 1:15 pm UTC timestamp that you stored, and the displayed result will not be 3:15 pm.

I don't know if this is common practice or even a good idea, so I would appreciate some feedback.

Comment: What is "UTC Timezone"?